# An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: RuntimeException Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Events

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

**error**

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: RuntimeException Message:
>   Unable to locate the model you have specified: Events Filename:
>   /home/dailysurvive/public_html/citymallgulberglahore.com/mall/system/core/Loader.php
>   Line Number: 344 Backtrace: File:
>   /home/dailysurvive/public_html/citymallgulberglahore.com/mall/application/controllers/Welcome.php
>   Line: 29 Function: model File:
>   /home/dailysurvive/public_html/citymallgulberglahore.com/mall/index.php
>   Line: 315 Function: require_once

the images for the error files are as following

Model.php

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Model Class
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Libraries
 * @author      EllisLab Dev Team
 * @link        https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html
 */
class CI_Model {

/**
 * Class constructor
 *
 * @return  void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    log_message('info', 'Model Class Initialized');
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * __get magic
 *
 * Allows models to access CI's loaded classes using the same
 * syntax as controllers.
 *
 * @param   string  $key
 */
public function __get($key)
{
    // Debugging note:
    //  If you're here because you're getting an error message
    //  saying 'Undefined Property: system/core/Model.php', it's
    //  most likely a typo in your model code.
    return get_instance()->$key;
}
```

}

Loader.php

```
    $model = ucfirst($model);
    if ( ! class_exists($model, FALSE))
    {
        foreach ($this->_ci_model_paths as $mod_path)
        {
            if ( ! file_exists($mod_path.'models/'.$path.$model.'.php'))
            {
                continue;
            }

            require_once($mod_path.'models/'.$path.$model.'.php');
            if ( ! class_exists($model, FALSE))
            {
                throw new RuntimeException($mod_path."models/".$path.$model.".php exists, but doesn't declare class ".$model);
            }

            break;
        }

        if ( ! class_exists($model, FALSE))
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('Unable to locate the model you have specified: '.$model);
        }
    }
    elseif ( ! is_subclass_of($model, 'CI_Model'))
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Class ".$model." already exists and doesn't extend CI_Model");
    }

    $this->_ci_models[] = $name;
    $CI->$name = new $model();
    return $this;
}
```

Welcome.php

```
public function index($data=null)
{
    //$this->load->view('welcome_message');
   $this->load->model("events");
   $data['records'] = $this->events->getAllRecords();


    $this->load->view('header',$data);
    $this->load->view('home',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer',$data);

}

function home()
{
    $data = array(
        'back_step' => '../',
    );


    $dat = array(

        'email'     => $this->input->post('email')
    );



    $this->load->model("events");
    $this->load->database();

   $res = $this->db->insert('subscribe',$dat);

    $data['records'] = $this->events->getAllRecords();

    $this->index($data);
```

index.php

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Comment: is issue still there ??

Answer (score 0):

1: Rename your model name from Events.php to Events_model.php
2: use $this->load->model('Events_model', 'events')

Comment: still facing the same issue

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your project directory and controller and model files?

Comment: sorry this was the code for event.php<?php
    class Events extends CI_Model
    {
        function getAllRecords()
        {
           $this->load->database();
           $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
            $q = $this->db->get("events");


            if($q->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return $q->result();
            }
            return array();
        }
    }
?>

Comment: Class name must be Events_model extends CI_Model